# Check if a date on a row is earlier than another date on the next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have the following code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='5/18/2019', end='7/22/2020', freq='S')

df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['start_timestamp'])
df['end_timestamp'] = date_rng
df['start_timestamp'] = np.random.randint(1589760000,1595376000,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['end_timestamp'] = np.random.randint(1589760000,1595376000,size=(len(date_rng)))
df = df[(df.end_timestamp/df.start_timestamp<=1.000009)&(df.end_timestamp/df.start_timestamp>=1.000001)]
df = df.sort_values(by=['start_timestamp','end_timestamp'])
df['start_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_timestamp'],unit='s')
df['end_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_timestamp'],unit='s')
```

As result, I have the following dataframe:

```
  start_timestamp     end_timestamp
2020-05-18 00:00:30 2020-05-18 00:54:07
2020-05-18 00:01:40 2020-05-18 03:50:39
2020-05-18 00:02:08 2020-05-18 02:39:41
2020-05-18 00:04:01 2020-05-18 00:47:25
2020-05-18 00:04:01 2020-05-18 02:26:50
2020-05-18 00:04:44 2020-05-18 02:17:53

                .
                .
                .
```

What should I do to ensure in my dataset that every `end_timestamp` is a datetime prior to the `start_timestamp` of its next row?

**SOLUTION THAT HAS BEEN IMPLEMENTED**

I basically transformed the dataset into an array, put it in ascending order and transformed it back into a dataframe. It may not be the most elegant of the solutions, but it worked correctly and generated consistent data for what I intend to use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='7/22/2019', end='7/22/2020', freq='S')

df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['start_timestamp'])
df['end_timestamp'] = date_rng
df['start_timestamp'] = np.random.randint(1563753600,1595376000,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['end_timestamp'] = np.random.randint(1563753600,1595376000,size=(len(date_rng)))
df = df[(df.end_timestamp/df.start_timestamp<=1.0000009)&(df.end_timestamp/df.start_timestamp>=1.0000001)]
df = df.to_numpy()
df = df.reshape(df.shape[0]*2,1)
df = np.sort(df,axis=0)
df = df.reshape(int(df.shape[0]/2),2)
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['start_timestamp','end_timestamp'])
df['start_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_timestamp'],unit='s')
df['end_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_timestamp'],unit='s')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code your logic and it's all fine right

1. `freq='S'` makes no sense you will generate as many rows as there are seconds between your start and end dates
2. after randomising start times use current and next row as seeds to random function for end time.  Did this as a list comprehension
3. been a bit smarter on getting UTC seconds at start and end of range

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
# date_rng = pd.date_range(start='5/18/2019', end='7/22/2020', freq='S')
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='5/18/2019', end='5/19/2019', freq='min')

sec = [(date_rng.min() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds(),
       (date_rng.max() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() ]
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['start_timestamp'])
df['start_timestamp'] = np.random.randint(sec[0],sec[1],size=(len(date_rng)))
df = df.sort_values(by="start_timestamp")
l = df["start_timestamp"].tolist()  # get randomised start times
l[-1] = sec[1] # set last time to end of range
# randomise end time between two start times
df['end_timestamp'] = [np.random.randint(l[i], l[i+1]) if i<len(l)-1  and l[i]<l[i+1] else l[i] for i, s in enumerate(l)]
df['start_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_timestamp'],unit='s')
df['end_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_timestamp'],unit='s')
```

Comment: I put the value in seconds because, in an application that will work with this data, I will need to work with this degree of refinement. Anyway, thanks. I will determine your answer as accepted.

Comment: since posting this answer I realised there is something more fundamental - a sorted list of random integers is almost equivalent to a sequence of integers.  You also noted that startdate and enddate are not independent random variables.    So this really comes back to maths / stats